# Make sure to link against non-system installed library

Tags: c++, linker, clang

I downloaded and compiled libevent in a custom folder, but I noticed there is also a system wide installation of libevent. But I want to link against the one I compiled.

My program looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <event2/bufferevent.h>
#include <event2/buffer.h>
#include <event2/listener.h>
#include <event2/util.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/frob.h>

int main()
{
  struct event_base *base;
  struct evconnlistener *listener;
  struct event *signal_event;

  base = event_base_new();

  std::cout << "Finished getting new event base" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Then, in the downloaded version of libevent, I made some modifications, like inserting `exit(-1)` into the `event_base_new()` function, compiled both, my program and libevent again and ran the executable. However, the program ran through without exiting.

Here is how I compiled:

```
clang++ -I/Users/max/Downloads/libevent-2.0.22-stable/include -Wall -g -c server.cpp
clang++ -Wall -g server.o -L/Users/max/Downloads/libevent-2.0.22-stable/ -levent -o server
```

Shouldn't that be enough to tell the linker to use my other version of libevent?

Comment: to specify a system include path on clang, use -isystem rather than -I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your library file (say, to `libevent_customized.a`) and provide to the linker the renamed library's name:

```
clang++ -Wall -g server.o -L/path/to/lib -levent_customized -o server
#                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can specify the library file using its full path as a regular argument (this will work only for a static library):

```
clang++ -Wall -g server.o /path/to/lib/libevent.a -o server
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, so system-installed libs are searched before the include paths are evaluated? I honestly didn't know that

Comment: Directories specified on the command line are searched before the default directories. However on ELF systems the linker searches for the dynamic version of the library before trying the static version. I guess that the system library was a dynamic one (`libevent.so`) while you had built yours as static (`libevent.a`).